# Vertically centered underscore

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the mathematical symbol equivalent to a vertically centered underscore ?
I need a symbol a little larger than a simple minus.

Comment: In what context do you need it? Should it be a binary operation symbol or have some other type?

Comment: In fact it's just as a bullet for a list.

Comment: Without knowing the context, I suggest a rather "hacky" way: `$\textrm{---}$` or with amsmath: `$\text{---}$`. This will put an em-dash inside an equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not looking for a mathematical symbol. You have the choice between `--` (en dash), `---` (em dash) or `\textthreequartersemdash` (with the `textcomp` package.

Here's an example for a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[--] One
\item[\textthreequartersemdash] Two
\item[---] Three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you decide for `\textthreequartersemdash`, it's better to load the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textthreequartersemdash}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In this way, all first level `itemize` lists will use the three quarter em dash.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches:

1) Use `$\textrm{---}$`

2) Use `$\text{---}$`

3) In text mode, you can write `--` for a hyphen or `---` for a line for intertext ---such as the one that would go here.

4) You can use `\package{tikz}` and set up a line as long as you want

5) I even think you could try with `\rule`, as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts)